# Put labels in each Path

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, view, path

I'm drawing some paths in XAML, but I want to put labels in each room. So:

**Example Plant**
[image]

I want to write for example: Corridor in a specific coordinate.

**Code XAML:** - this is not the actual code for this plant but mine is using the same MINICode - M & Z

```
<StackPanel>
   <Viewbox Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="600" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="600">
        <Grid>

            <Path Fill="#ff221e1f" Data="F1 M 65.778,45.310 L 85.092,45.310 L 85.092,47.630 L 68.504,47.630 L 68.504,63.174 L 83.700,63.174 L 83.700,65.494 L 68.504,65.494 L 68.504,84.402 L 65.778,84.402 L 65.778,45.310 Z"/>
            <Path Fill="#ff221e1f" Data="F1 M 95.300,64.218 L 101.505,64.218 C 107.538,64.218 111.482,60.854 111.482,55.692 C 111.482,49.718 107.074,47.282 100.926,47.282 C 98.257,47.282 96.286,47.572 95.300,47.804 L 95.300,64.218 Z M 92.574,45.832 C 94.952,45.310 98.316,45.020 100.984,45.020 C 106.087,45.020 109.278,46.122 111.540,48.268 C 113.222,49.892 114.266,52.502 114.266,55.228 C 114.266,60.506 111.133,63.870 106.610,65.436 L 106.610,65.552 C 109.742,66.538 111.713,69.496 112.642,73.846 C 113.976,79.936 114.730,82.836 115.542,84.402 L 112.642,84.402 C 112.062,83.242 111.192,79.820 110.148,74.890 C 108.988,69.264 106.551,66.712 101.390,66.480 L 95.300,66.480 L 95.300,84.402 L 92.574,84.402 L 92.574,45.832 Z"/>
            <Path StrokeThickness="3.0" Stroke="#ff221e1f" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Data="F1 M 179.125,90.312 C 179.125,139.362 139.362,179.125 90.312,179.125 C 41.263,179.125 1.500,139.362 1.500,90.312 C 1.500,41.263 41.263,1.500 90.312,1.500 C 139.362,1.500 179.125,41.263 179.125,90.312 Z"/>
            <Path StrokeThickness="3.0" Stroke="#ff221e1f" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Data="F1 M 75.533,117.798 L 103.986,117.798"/>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</StackPanel>
```

How can I put the labels in the coordinates I want?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [`Canvas`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as panel instead of the `Grid`, then you can position elements with the attached properties [`Canvas.Left`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.left%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Canvas.Top`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.top%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Hi @H.B. thanks for your answer, but I want to write in the middle of the rooms. Like room A, room B, Hall 1, Hall 2. Do you know another way? I need to define the correct spot.

Comment: Well, there are algorithms for finding some kind of center for polygons, then you just need to put your label there and shift it back by 50% in both directions (e.g. using a `TranslateTransform`)

Comment: And in terms of XAML to write the labels? It isn't sufficient just to put <Label Content="{Binding groupLabels"/> right? I have to define position, but I don't really know how to do it. I found one of that algorithms and I found all the centers for all the figures in the paths, but I have to pass them to somewhere in the XAML with the text. Can you help me achieve that?

Comment: @Antoine: As noted in answer, you set `Canvas.Left`/`Top` on the `Label` to position it. If you have a collection of labels you will need to bind it to an `ItemsControl` with a `Canvas` as its `ItemsPanel` and the label as its `ItemTemplate`, you can find answers about how to set that up easily on Stackoverflow, been asker dozens of times.